# Find the number of zeros of $z^{3}+2z^{2}-z-2+e^{z}$ which lies in the left half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

I am working on an exercise that

> How many solutions of equation $$z^{3}+2z^{2}-z-2+e^{z}=0,$$ lie in the left half plane?

The first idea was definitely the Rouche's Theorem, but then we need to use a big circle (for $R$ large enough) centered at the origin, and then we use Rouche's theorem.

**But the problem is** it is really hard to argue that this function has the same number of zeros between left semi-circle and right semi-circle, so that we can just use half of the total number of zeros.

**The difficulty of applying Argument Principle is also self-evident.**

Without these two tools, what should I start with to compute the number of zeros of this function?

Thank you!

Comment: If the left half-plane is hard to look at, you can map it to the unit circle and work with the new function there. Rouche's theorem could work, but the argument principle is always more powerful. Every computation of number roots that can be done using Rouche can also be done using the argument principle, but there are lots of problems in which applying Rouche is hard but routine computation with the argument principle. You can also apply directly the argument principle along the imaginary line travelled upwards.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy but in this case it is hard to compute the contour integral of $f(z)/f'(z)$, and it is hard to argue $f(z)$ has no pole and never vanish on the boundary of the contour...

Comment: You don't need to compute the integral directly, only to use its geometric interpretation as the winding number of the image of the curve by the function. So, what you need to compute is how many times the image of the imaginary axis by the function in question winds around the origin.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh! okay. I forgot about the winding number...

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy let me compute a little bit and I will edit this post! Thank you!

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy so there is only one zero for the function? also, you are actually  using $\infty$ together with the imaginary axis to create a closed contour (like we bend over the axis), am I right?

Comment: Yes, but if that sounds strange, you could first map the left half-plane to the unit disc, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy so if the questions asked about the number of zeros lying in the right half plane, can I still solve it by analyzing the image of imaginary axis (including $\infty$)? Similarly, is analyzing the image of the real axis applicable if the question asks about the number of zeros lying in the upper half plane?

Comment: Yes, but the right half-plane is the interior of the imaginary axis travelled downwards. The image will be the curve above travelled in the opposite direction. So, it looks going upwards, from he third quadrant part to the second quadrant part. Since $0$ is not to the left of this path, it is outside.

Comment: By the way, I did something wrong in my computation above. Let me check.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh! no problem. I got your idea!

Comment: Ah! The problem is that I can't just travel the imaginary axis only. The direct application of the argument principle should be to, for example, a curve formed by the segment $[-Ri,Ri]$ of the imaginary axis and the arc $Re^{it}$ for $t\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$. When you compute the image of that arc by your function that adds a wind around zero. I was just shrinking that arc to the point at infinity, but there is a non-zero residue at infinity for $f'/f$, which should be counted. So, one could either compute this residue or just comput e the image of the arc too.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gqta8gzigx) is a picture.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy wow. Sorry for the late reply! You are brilliant!! (again would you like to post the answer?)

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy how did you get to know $f'/f$ has a non-zero residue at $\infty$?

Comment: I didn't compute it. It is just a consequence of the function having three zeros on the plane. That comment is not supposed to be part of the computation, just an observation I made, partly to myself, for having used the image of the imaginary axis alone the first time I computed, instead of the image of the loop $[-R,R]$ together with the arc $Re^{it}$ for $t\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy how did you decide to use such an arc, instead of other arcs? (I am sorry for so many questions since I am not really familiar with the winding number..)

Comment: Any loop that is big enough to enclose the roots would do. Just pick one as simple as possible such that the winding number of its image is easy to compute.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh! okay! Thank you so much for your great comments!!!

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I am sorry but in the last comment, the roots enclosed in the contour are the roots of $f/f'$ or $f$?

Comment: The roots of $f$, which are poles of $f'/f$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy but if I know the roots of $f$, I can directly give the number of roots of $f$ right? why would we go a long way and to use the winding number? (I am sorry if the question is dumb....)

Comment: We don't know the roots or their number. We only do the computation of the winding number for that path for $R$ large. Then note that the winding number is $2$ for all $R$ large. That implies that the number of roots of $f$ is $2$. The winding number we computed from the picture, which we don't need to compute exactly, only a rough sketch like the skills that you learn in calculus is enough. For example, it suffices to know to which quadrants the curve is moving as you traverse it. This is, knowing the sign changes of its real an imaginary parts.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy ah. okay. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $p(z)=z^3+2z^2-z-2=(z+2)(z-1)(z+1)$. For purely imaginary $z$ it follows that $\lvert p(z) \rvert \geq 2$.  For some large enough fixed radius $R$ and $\lvert z \rvert = R$ also $\lvert p(z) \rvert \geq 2$.  Since $\lvert \exp(z) \rvert \leq 1$ on the left half plane you can use Rouché to conclude that the number of zeroes on the left half plane equals the number of roots of $p(z)$ there.

Comment: the problem is still that Rouche can only be applied to the disc, so I need to argue the right half disc and left half disk contains the same number of zeros....

Comment: No Rouché is valid for any contour.

Comment: yes. you are right. a second thought reminded me that the Rouche is proved by using Argument principle, which is valid for any contours, so Rouche should also be valid for any contour. I will go to read the proof again to see if there will be anything wrong in the proof if we argue over any contour.

Comment: I checked, yes, Rouche can be applied to any contour.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Making $z= x + i y$ and taking real and imaginary parts we have

$$
\cases{
x^3+2 x^2-3 x y^2+e^x \cos (y)-x-2 y^2-2=0\\
3 x^2 y+4 x y+e^x \sin (y)-y^3-y=0
}
$$

also

$$
\cos(y)^2+\sin(y)^2=1\Rightarrow e^{-2 x} \left((x-1)^2+y^2\right) \left((x+1)^2+y^2\right) \left((x+2)^2+y^2\right)-1=0
$$

contains all needed solutions.

Follows a plot showing the zero locations at the intersection of red and blue curves, as well in black, the last relationship.

[image]

and also a detailed plot.

[image]